# show Pin always in center on map view and calculate lat long,address in ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview

In my ios application i want to place a pin on map that will always show callout by default.on that callut i am showing lat,long of pin.

What i want is pin always remain in center of map.and when user move map pin do not get moved but its lat long get changed after moving map.

i also want to show address from that lat,long.

Please guide what are the ways.

i have tried this code to

```
[mMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
MyAnnotation* obj = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithLocation:mMapView.centerCoordinate withPinType:StartPoint];
[obj setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f",mMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude,mMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude]];
[mMapView selectAnnotation:obj animated:YES];
[mMapView addAnnotation:obj];
```

zoom map at current location
add pin on map center
showing lat long

Problem - when i move map.pin also get moved and lat long did not get changed

Answer (score 1):

In your -viewDidLoad method add following code,

```
[mMapView.userLocation addObserver:self  
                                forKeyPath:@"location"  
                                   options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)  
                                   context:NULL];
```

Now include the following method,

```
// Listen to change in the userLocation
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
{
    [object setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f",mMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude,mMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude]];
    [mMapView selectAnnotation:object animated:YES];
}
```

Please make sure your annotation object is class object.

Hope this will help...